# Mouse position constraints in openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers-3

I have setup my [map](http://lostminions.org/h1z1/map/index2.php) with a 8192x8192 image, yet if you notice when clicking around the map the mouse position is a huge number like (20049402.9634) in the corner (with 0,0 being the center). Does anyone know a way to make it act like the older version of OpenLayers where if I set the extent to [-4096, -4096, 4096, 4096] it'll actually make the corners of the image be 4096, 4096 in the respective corners.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can also pass an `extent` property to the view, which limits panning to the given extent.

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at your map(link you provided)  and everything seems OK. The projection is 3857 and all corners are +/- 4096, +/- 4096. If I have missed something please explain in more detail and I will take another look to see if I can resolve the problem.

Comment: They only show as 4096 cause I crudely am scaling the mouse position 'var scaleFactor = 4096/20037000;'